# Problema Express con Jest: "A worker process has failed to exit gracefully" usando async/await

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, sequelize.js, jestjs

estoy haciendo unos test con Express (con tsc), Sequelize y Jest y obtengo el siguiente mensaje al iniciar los Test:

```
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
```

Me he aproximado bastante al problema, lo que ocurre es que me estoy saltando usar await en el archivo que les dejo a continuación -> users.ts:81
https://github.com/diegoulloao/bananasplit-express-template/blob/dev/src/app/models/user.ts

Estoy utilizando async y await, sin promesas.

El problema es que no sé de qué forma cambiar mi código para que pueda poner la función _sync como async y hacer el await, porque al hacerlo entonces en la línea :71 de la función init tendría que también hacerla asíncrona con await en la llamada a _async, pero si lo hago obtengo el siguiente error de compilación:

```
/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app/controllers/controller.ts:89:43 - error TS2339: Property 'findAll' does not exist on type 'Promise<typeof User>'.

89                 const result = await User.findAll()
                                             ~~~~~~~

  src/app/controllers/controller.ts:89:43
    89                 const result = await User.findAll()
                                                 ~~~~~~~
    Did you forget to use 'await'?

    at createTSError (/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:425:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:530:36)
    at Object.compile (/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:735:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:814:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:817:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:644:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:771:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo??

---

Quiero dar por cerrado el tema, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
El problema principal se arregló pero me deriva a un warning en jest.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIONADO!**

Puse esto al comienzo antes de ejecutar cualquier test en mi archivo de tests:

```
beforeAll( async () => {

    // Prevents error: getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed
    await sequelize.sync()

} )
```

Y esto al final después de todos los tests:

```
afterAll( done => {

    // Closing the DB connection allows Jest to exit successfully:
    sequelize.close()
    done()

})
```

Comment: Las preguntas se indican como solucionadas marcando como aceptada la respuesta que solucionó el problema

Comment: Esto trato de hacer pero me sale esto: "Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta en 20 horas"

Comment: Entonces solo queda esperar a que el tiempo se concluya para hacer la acción recomendada

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**
el metodo `sync` de la clase `model` de Sequelize retorna una promesa. Si retornas la promesa entonces Jest podra esperar a que termine de ejecutarse antes de correr las evaluaciones.

asi debe verse `_sync`:

```js
public static async _sync() {
  return User.sync({ force: true });
}
```

**Respuesta original**

Lo que necesitas es envolver el codigo del metodo `_sync` en una promesa y retornar la promesa:

```js
public static _sync() {
  const thePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const result = User.sync({ force: true })
    resolve(result);
  });
  return thePromise;
}
```

Luego en tu prueba:

```js
it('blah', async () => {
  await User.findAll().then(result => {
  // agrega mas validaciones antes del return
  return expect(result).toBeTruthy()
});
}
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando código moderno, sin promesas.
Cuál sería la forma usando async/await ?

Hice una actualización del detalle de error.

Comment: En ese caso tienes que usar `async` en tu metodo y seria asi: `public static async _sync()` eso envolvera tu codigo en una promesa automaticamente. Creo que lo que pasa es que `User.sync` retorna una promesa. Cual es el tipo de retorno de ese metodo?

Comment: No está tipado el tipo de retorno, y lo estoy probando así tal cual como dices con async await y es ahí cuando tira el error

Comment: El problema es que si User.sync es asincrono entonces la prueba terminara de correr antes de que User.sync termine. Trata retornando User.sync:
`_sync() {  return User.sync({force:true}) }`

Comment: Efectivamente, leyendo la documentacion, User.sync retorna una promesa:
https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync

Si retornas `return User.sync({force: true})` deberia funcionar

Comment: /Users/diego/Desktop/Proyectos/mern-auth-template/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app/controllers/controller.ts:89:43 - error TS2551: Property 'findAll' does not exist on type 'Promise<typeof User | Model<any, any>>'. Did you mean 'finally'?

89                 const result = await User.findAll()
                                             ~~~~~~~

Comment: Sigue el mismo problema. Mi aplicación solo usa una base de datos vacía mysql llamada test. Está el repositorio actualizado https://github.com/diegoulloao/bananasplit-express-template

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104474/discussion-between-diego-ulloa-and-jorge-armando-palm).